# Does Vim have a character limit for regexes?

Tags: vim

I just tried (naively) to put together a macro for upper-casing an arbitrary set of SQL reserved words.

```
:nnoremap <leader>c :s/\(\<use\>\)\|\(\<create\>\)\|\(\<select\>\)\|\(\<update\>\)\|\(\<delete\>\)\|\(\<not\>\)\|\(\<null\>\)\|\(\<unique\>\)\|\(\<constraint\>\)\|\(\<references\>\)\|\(\<join\>\)\|\(\<on\>\)\|\(\<inner\>\)\|\(\<outer\>\)\|\(\<left\>\)\|\(\<group\>\)\|\(\<order\>\)\|\(\<having\>\)\|\(\<by\>\)/\U&/g<CR>
```

The macro is written to my .vimrc, which loads up fine.  But when I run the macro Vim spits out some errors:

```
E872: (NFA regexp) Too many '('
E51: Too many \(
E476: Invalid command
```

I've been searching around but found nothing to indicate that there are limits on regexes.  My best read on the errors is that I've failed to properly escape something, but I can't find it.

Have I exceeded some limit on regexes here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not about the limit of characters in regex, it is about the limit of number of groups in your regex.

Vim can handle max 10 regex groups, (`\0....\9`), I didn't count your codes, but you should have more than 10 groups in your regex.

The constant (10) was defined in `regexp.h`

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/0b9e4d1224522791c0dbbd45742cbd688be823f3/src/regexp.h#L22

And it was used to validate user's regex, like here :

https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/af98a49dd0ef1661b4998f118151fddbf6e4df75/src/regexp.c#L1539

Comment: You  can have up to 9 groups (\1 to \9), the tenth being \0 which refers to the entire match. The OP's regex doesn't need grouping anyway and works fine if you simply delete the brackets.

Comment: @EndreBoth  Thanks for the comment. I think we are looking at the question from different angle. I am focusing on "why do I have this error msg" or "`Have I exceeded some limit on regexes here?`". But you are absolutely right, there is huge room to optimize OP's regex.

Comment: Ah ha!  I didn't realize the grouping wasn't necessary with the pipes.  Kent, thanks for the info - good to know there are limits on groupings.

Comment: In case you need many groupings you can use `\%(` and `\)` without limit, but these groupings can't be accessed via `\1`, ..., `\9`.

Answer (score 10):

You can only have capture patterns \1..\9. If you need more groupings, but don't need to capture them all, you can use non-capturing groups with the `\%(pattern\)` syntax:

```
/abc\%(def\)ghi/
```

Comment: Underrated answer: This one gives a possible solution